# alternative to listagg in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have this query i need to convert from oracle 11g to 10g, anyone can help me out with the process, since in oracle 10g it does not support listagg

```
(SELECT REQ.ID_REQUISICAO, 1 AVISO,
                      LISTAGG(CF.desc_quest || ' Sim. ' || REQ.C_NOTA_QUEST, chr(10))
                       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) ALERTAS
                      FROM SII_CF_QUEST CF INNER JOIN SII_REQ_QUEST REQ
                      ON CF.id_quest = REQ.id_quest
                      WHERE CF.id_aviso IS NOT NULL
                      AND REQ.id_sn_quest = 1
                      GROUP BY REQ.ID_REQUISICAO) ;
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have a look at these alternatives: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REQ.ID_REQUISICAO, 1 AVISO, To_Char(wm_concat(CF.desc_quest || ' Sim. ' ||REQ.C_NOTA_QUEST)) AS ALERTAS
FROM SII_CF_QUEST CF INNER JOIN SII_REQ_QUEST REQ
                      ON CF.id_quest = REQ.id_quest
                      WHERE CF.id_aviso IS NOT NULL
                      AND REQ.id_sn_quest = 1
                      GROUP BY REQ.ID_REQUISICAO ;
```

Solved my problem with this

Comment: you can also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558016/oracle-sql-listagg/53562671#53562671 as an alternative with elegant `sys_connect_by_path` function.